# Работа с системными файлами Android

Tags: java, android, файлы

Здравствуйте. Великое множество различных статей по работе с файлами Android, но не нашел ничего по работе с системными файлами. Необходимо прочитать один xml файл из системной папки, но как это сделать я не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Никак это не сделать. Потому что доступа нет.
А если рутнуть и получить доступ, то работа с ним ничем не отличается от чтения любого другого файла.